# SQL. Comparing value from current row versus the value resulted from the same comparison of the previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a script that would compare and get the higher value from current row versus the value resulted from the same comparison of the previous row.

[image: Sample Table]

For example:

1. Row 2 Column 'Given' > Row 5 Column 'Result'. Therefore, Row 2 Column 'Result' gets the same value in Row 2 Column 'Given'
2. Row 3 Column 'Given' < Row 2 Column 'Result'. Therefore, we will retain the value in Row 2 Column 'Result'. Same Thing with Row 4
3. Rpw 5 Column 'Given' is now > Row 4 Column 'Result'. Therefore we will get the value in Row 5 Column.

My problem is it needs to be referenced on the same field that is yet to be created. Do you know any steps on how to attack this problem? Thank you!

Comment: I think you might be looking for a cte with recursion here. Your current row results are dependent on the previous record values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for something like this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [RowID] INT
   ,[given] INT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([RowID], [given])
VALUES (1, 10)
      ,(2, 15)
      ,(3, 12)
      ,(4, 14)
      ,(5, 20);

SELECT [given]
      ,MAX([given]) OVER (ORDER BY [RowID])
FROM @DataSource;
```

[image]

You can check the [OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) clause as you may need to use `PARTITION BY` or `ROWS BETWEEN` in your real case.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Initially, I was trying to use the CURSOR statement as well as nested CTE, but this one's better and faster!